# extra space in acronyms on document

Tags: document-classes, acronyms, documentclass-writing, acro

I'm working with some acronyms and when I compile every acronym has extra space, for example with this abbreviation, Higher Education ( HE) and not Higher Education (HE). Even after the first time is like: the  HE is... (extra spaces)

```
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%% Thesis.tex -- MAIN FILE (the one that you compile with LaTeX)
%% ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

% Set up the document
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
\graphicspath{Figures/}  % Location of the graphics files (set up for graphics to be in PDF format)
\usepackage{verbatim}  % Needed for the "comment" environment to make LaTeX comments
\usepackage{vector}  % Allows "\bvec{}" and "\buvec{}" for "blackboard" style bold vectors in maths
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\parskip=0cm
\usepackage[tooltip]{acro} 


\def\mycolor#1{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\DeclareAcronym{HE}{short =\mycolor{HE}, long = Higher Education, class = abbrev}

\begin{document}

\clearpage  % Start a new page
\chapter{List of Abbreviations}
\lhead{\emph{List of abbreviation}}
\printacronyms[heading=none]



\chapter{Introduction}

the very susceptible area is precisely \ac{HE}, which runs under the seal of "bulwark of the Revolution" and that, beyond from a political argument, it becomes for many also a principle for research. The \ac{HE} is very ...




\end{document}  % The End
%% ---------------------------
```

Can anybody help to me?
the other two files needed to run code are:

[Thesis.cls](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1izb5qrUfc9Y5mV2KNxT3jmiqkP6ObvFB)
and 
[lstpatch.sty](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qJsgWC3cXdNvbHwaV1oaxp-ZVpY80CQt)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is spurious spaces. The file `Thesis.cls` has *a lot* of them and should be revised by someone who knows what they're doing.

The spaces in which are causing the problem here only become visible in a certain combination: `acro` using the `tooltip` option and the following lines in `Thesis.cls`:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
   \let\\\space
}
```

It should be

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
   \let\\\space
}
```

(notice the `%`). Feel safe to make this change in `Thesis.cls`. but you should also contact whoever distributes the class file (maybe with a pointer to your question here on tex.sx).

A more minimal example to observe the same effect (which also moves the formatting of the acronym to `\acsetup`, uses `\newcommand` rather than `\def` and corrects the wrong `"..."` to ``` ``...'' ```:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\mycolor[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

\acsetup{
  tooltip ,
  short-format = \mycolor
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
   \let\\\space
}

\DeclareAcronym{HE}{
  short = HE,
  long = Higher Education,
  class = abbrev
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{List of Abbreviations}

\printacronyms[heading=none]

\chapter{Introduction}

the very susceptible area is precisely \ac{HE}, which runs under the seal of
``bulwark of the Revolution'' and that, beyond from a political argument, it
becomes for many also a principle for research. The \ac{HE} is very ...

\end{document}
```